# FileUpload.FileName behavior when there is a semi-colon or opening bracket in the file name

Tags: c#, string, char, contains

I have a FileUpload control, and there are certain restrictions on the file name, certain characters that shouldn't be allowed.  The following code works for most characters, but for some reason not others:

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    if (FileUpload1.FileName.Contains('#') ||
        FileUpload1.FileName.Contains('&') ||
        FileUpload1.FileName.Contains(';') ||
        FileUpload1.FileName.Contains('{') ||
        FileUpload1.FileName.Contains('}') ||
        FileUpload1.FileName.Contains('+'))
    {
        //error: bad character detected
    }
}
```

I could probably do this another (better) way, with a regular expression, but first I really want to know why the above doesn't work.

The following characters **are** detected in the FileName:

```
# & } +
```

The following characters **are not** detected in the FileName:

```
; {
```

Why?

**Edit:** examples of file names that I've tried.

- Final+Version.pdf //+ detected
- Final;Version.pdf //; NOT detected
- WhyHello{there.pdf //{ NOT detected
- Policies}20120303.pdf //} detected

As mentioned in the comments below, there is no problem with these characters on strings, so maybe it's a problem with the value of "FileName" or the way the FileUploader handles the file name?

**Edit 2:**
Breakpoint step through shows that, using Policies{20120303.pdf as an example, the value of FileName is Policies.pdf.  So this is not a problem with .Contains() anymore, but with FileUpload and FileName.

So the new question is, how can I handle this?  I don't want files with these characters to go through, and I don't want the submitted files to be named differently from what the user named them.  So if someone tries to submit 'Policies{20120303.pdf', I need one of two results:

1. invalid name is detected, procedure aborted
2. submit the file with the complete and original name, Policies{20120303.pdf

**Edit 3:**
If I submit a file with the following name: **foo;bar{baz.txt**, the value of FileUpload.FileName is "**foo.txt**"

**Edit 4:**
Thanks to some helpful comments below, I tried using a different browser (Chrome), and it works just fine!  The file name stays intact, even with foo;bar{baz.txt.  I use Opera, and it wasn't working.  I guess that narrows it down quite a lot to a browser specific issue.  I don't think there's gonna be any way to make this work properly in Opera, unless someone has any ideas?

Comment: `"{".Contains("{")` works for me. Is the browser encoding the file name badly?

Comment: Then maybe it's something wrong with the FileName and FileUploader.  I just edited my question with file names I've tried.

Comment: I just tried `"WhyHello{there.pdf".Contains("{")` and I got True. It's encoding.

Comment: Why dont you check the result of `FileUpload1.FileName` ?

Comment: Note that the OP could be using the Contains extension method from linq. String supports IEnumerable<char> and the Contains method defined on string actually takes a string as the input parameter, so the Contains method in the question is almost certainly the linq version.  Not that that explains the behavior described in the question.

Comment: I've updated my question.  This is no longer a question about .Contains, but rather FileUpload and FileName.   I'll change the topic name of this question.

Comment: Please show us what the value of `FileUpload1.FileName` is when you provide a file called "`foo;bar{baz.txt`".

Comment: @Dai Edited the question again with that bit of info, thanks.

Comment: I guess, this is because , some characters like `&` , `#`, `+` (as they are special, in web url) cannot be a part of files on web. So, FileUpload control filters those chars.

Have you tried the `FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName` instead ?

Comment: I tried simulate your problem with filename "foo;bar{baz.txt," but i'm able to detect "{" & ";"

Comment: Unfortunately no go on PostedFile.FileName.  Thanks though.

Comment: @hallie Thanks!  Since you said that, I tried another browser, and it DOES work in Chrome.  I use Opera.  At least that helps to narrow the cause down a bit.

Comment: There is a good chance that browser just does not send these characters. Use some HTTP debugger/watcher (i.e. [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)) to see how requests posted by browser look like.

Comment: ";" may be used as a character to separate several file names. "{" and "}" looks like characters used for string formatting.  "{" is the opening one but "}" is the closing one so it's matched if no "{" was previously found. Did you try escaping these?

Comment: Side note - why not whitelist *good* characters, rather than trying to blacklist "*bad*" characters? I'm not sure what you're trying to protect, but are you sure you're bad character list is complete? It's a lot easier to be sure with whitelists.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code in my program to check the filename:

```
filename = txtFileName.Text;
if (filename == "" || (filename.IndexOfAny(System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) != -1))
{
// Ask for a new file name, or whatever else you need to do.
}
```

In my case, however, I'm checking the user provided string before setting the file name in the file object. I think that would probably solve your problem as well.

I'm guessing that somewhere there's a function that alters the string before you get to the point of verifying it.